tikz & pgfplot question: shifting "at"
I try to put two drawings next to each other, one of them is a pgfplot. They are one over the other, despite the at={(8,0)} command inside the plot command. So here is my attempt:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}
  {  
    \draw (\x, 0) -- (\x,5) ;
  }
  \foreach \x in {0, 0.5, ..., 5}
  {  
    \draw (0,\x) -- (5,\x) ;
  }
        
    
  \begin{axis}[hide axis]
  \addplot3 [at={(8,0)}, surf,      colormap={bw}{  gray(0cm)=(1);  gray(1cm)=(1); }, domain=-4:0, domain y=-4:0,
  samples=10, samples y=10,  fill=none,     variable=\u, variable y=\v,
  point meta=0 ]
   ( {u}, {v}, {cos(u) + cos(v)} );
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


Additional question, if you had a hint how the surface lines could become black instead on gray that would be awesome!  Thank you

The code, as it is shown in your question, doesn't compile.

Please also don't mix different questions in a single post.

at is an axis option

i) Your document is not runnable. ii) It's unclear to me what you want to create. If you want the entire pgfplot to be shifted 8cm to the right, put the axis environment in a scope environment: \begin{scope}[xshift=80mm] ....... \end{scope}
PS: Your TikZ plot looks like a grid; You could also work completely with pgfplots here.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}{\draw (\x,0) -- (\x,5);}
\foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,5}{\draw (0,\x) -- (5,\x);}
\begin{axis}[hide axis, xshift=8cm]
\addplot3[
mesh, draw=black,
domain=-4:0, samples=10, variable=u,
domain y=-4:0, samples y=10, variable y=v,
]( {u}, {v}, {cos(u) + cos(v)} );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



thank you for the answer (and corrections in latex code).
